# Marker coordinates in the "mouseover" listener for a dimple.plot.line

Tags: dimple.js

I'm trying to add a tooltip to the series for a dimple.plot.line.

By adding a listener to the series like this

```
var seriesProcessingTime = chart.addSeries("Date", dimple.plot.line, [timeAxis, processingTimeAxis])
seriesProcessingTime.lineMarkers = true;
...
seriesProcessingTime.addEventHandler("mouseover", onHoverProcessingTime);
```

Inside the `onHover...()` method, when calling `e.selectedShape.attr("x")` a `NaN` value is returned. What attribute should be called to get the coordinates of a marker in a dimple.plot.line?

Thank you, 
Adrian

Comment: e.selectedShape.attr("cx") and e.selectedShape.attr("cy") will return the circle's center coordinates